# Which chart will be suitable for employees wise on deliverable for 12 months?

Tags: javascript, angular, fusioncharts

[image]Attached image, I am mentioning engineer data for 3 months. i want to represent the data in chart. So i need suitable chart for representing the data. i just mentioned sample data for 3 months. i have to represent data in chart for 12 months.

Employee Data

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [ngx-charts](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/bar-vertical). They provide different d3.js based charts that can be used in Angular.

I think your usecase needs a custom chart, like a combination of the `grouped-vertical-bar-chart` inside a `grouped-vertical-bar-chart`.

E.g.: "syam" would represent a group of bars "3, 50 and 23" inside the greater group "February". "naveen" would also represent a group of bars inside that "February" group.

There is no such chart available in the ngx-charts, but custom charts can be easily implemented. Please take a look at [this](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/custom-charts) documentation.